# Please interpret this r code for me

Tags: r, time-series

```
library(tidyverse) # Includes the packages ggplot2 and tidyr, which we         use below

# Get the time values for the time series
Time = attributes(co2)[[1]]
Time = seq(Time[1],Time[2], length.out=(Time[2]-Time[1])*Time[3])

# Convert td to data frame
dat = cbind(Time, with(td, data.frame(Observed=x, Trend=trend,          Seasonal=seasonal, Random=random)))

ggplot(gather(dat, component, value, -Time), aes(Time, value)) +
facet_grid(component ~ ., scales="free_y") +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y=expression(CO[2]~(ppm)), x="Year") +
  ggtitle(expression(Decomposed~CO[2]~Time~Series)) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

I know it is about time series decomposition with ggplot. I need explanation on line 3 and 4 mostly. I want to apply monthly time series on the code.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a vector `Time` of length of at least 3.

```
seq(Time[1],Time[2], length.out=(Time[2]-Time[1])*Time[3])
```

creates a sequence from `Time[1]` to `Time[2]` and the resulting vector has the length as calculated in `Time[2]-Time[1])*Time[3]`.

The following line just binds some objects into a working data.frame. Data.frames are necessary to be able to plot with ggplot2. `ggplot2` code is more or less basic boilerplate stuff which you should be able to discern yourself (see the [superb documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/)).

You could try it yourself, even if you don't have the data.

```
Time <- c(1, 10, 5)
seq(from = Time[1], to = Time[2], length.out = (Time[2] - Time[1]) * Time[3])

[1]  1.000000  1.204545  1.409091  1.613636  1.818182  2.022727  2.227273
[8]  2.431818  2.636364  2.840909  3.045455  3.250000  3.454545  3.659091
[15]  3.863636  4.068182  4.272727  4.477273  4.681818  4.886364  5.090909
[22]  5.295455  5.500000  5.704545  5.909091  6.113636  6.318182  6.522727
[29]  6.727273  6.931818  7.136364  7.340909  7.545455  7.750000  7.954545
[36]  8.159091  8.363636  8.568182  8.772727  8.977273  9.181818  9.386364
[43]  9.590909  9.795455 10.000000
```

I will task you to do the reset with your data.